# Jenkins 2.x is hidden from Windows Service list

Tags: jenkins, windows-services

When installing Jenkins 2.0 on Windows Server, the result is that it runs as a Windows Service.

It can be stopped/started on the command line using `net stop jenkins & net start jenkins`.

However, Jenkins does not appear in the  `Administrative tools > Services` program.

Is there a way to view/control the service from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in later 2.0 versions, verified with version 2.15.

The `Jenkins` service now appears in the list of Windows services.